# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2) when I try to capture a webcam images

Tags: python, error-handling, deep-learning, gesture-recognition, webcam-capture

I want to apply the python code published in the following page link
[https://data-flair.training/blogs/sign-language-recognition-python-ml-opencv/]
I faced a problem with using the data augmented from the camera, when I want to create the dataset by building it from the captured webcam images, and when I want to evaluate the model. Webcam opened and closd at the same time with the following error message:

```
line 32, in segment_hand 
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresholded.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)....

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)"
```

Can anyone please help me how can I overcome the problem with all my thanks.

Regard..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `cv2.findContours` only returns 2 values not 3. Check the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

So you can change your code like this,

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresholded.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```